# How to use PIO one bit shift to FIFO on Pico in micropython?

Tags: pi-pico, micropython

I'm trying to port the [Pico C/C++ SDK example on PIO FIFOs](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/pico/raspberry-pi-pico-c-sdk.pdf#nameddest=_pio_program) into micropython.  I'm unable to get the `out()` instruction to work as intended.  I've tested the generic micropython [pio_blink.py sample](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-micropython-examples/blob/master/pio/pio_blink.py), which use `set()`, and of course, it works without any issue.  But my attempts to port the C sample program [hello pio](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-examples/tree/master/pio/hello_pio) failed to light the LED.

Can anyone figure out how to port the [hello pio](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-examples/tree/master/pio/hello_pio) C example to micropython?  Here's my attempt, which ran without error, but didn't blink the LED.

```
import time
import rp2
from machine import Pin

# Define the blink program.  It has one GPIO to bind to on the out instruction, which is an output pin.
@rp2.asm_pio(out_init=rp2.PIO.OUT_LOW, out_shiftdir=rp2.PIO.SHIFT_RIGHT)
def blink():
    label("loop")
    pull()
    out(pins, 1)
    jmp("loop")

# Instantiate a state machine with the blink program, with out bound to Pin(25) (LED on the Pico board)
sm = rp2.StateMachine(0, blink, out_base=Pin(25))

# Run the state machine.  The LED should blink at 1 Hz
sm.active(1)
while True:
    time.sleep_ms(500)
    sm.put(1)
    time.sleep_ms(500)
    sm.put(0)
sm.active(0)
```

Anyone see where I went wrong here?

Comment: According to this reference, https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/rp2.html , the second argument of `out()` is the number of bits to shift out. However this reference, https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/rp2.StateMachine.html , indicates that `put()` pushes words onto the state machine's `TX FIFO`. Should the `out()` specify a count for the number of bits in a single word?

Comment: @RichardChambers turns out the missing `out_shiftdir` was the problem (since corrected).  The `out_init` tuple must have a size >= your largest `out` bit argument.  Since both are 1, I'm ok, but there is no clear documentation on what the default shift dir is,  So apparently that is where I was off base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the bug was in the absence of an `out_shiftdir` argument.  It can be named either in the `StateMachine` object or the `pio_asm` object, but they should always be named.

I updated the question to include it.  As a rule of thumb... And `pio_asm` blocks that have an `out` must define `out_base`, `out_init`, and `out_shiftdir`.  These are declared either in the `pio_asm`, `StateMachine` or sometimes either.